# Can one see the source code of an app created with cocos2d-js?

Tags: cocos2d-js

Since cocos2d-js is javascript, couldn't one easily extract the source code ?

I don't see this mentioned explicitly anywhere, but since javascript is interpreted, it seems like it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the command cocos -p web -m release and it makes a version a bit obfuscated (everything in a line) but still anyone can get your code.

There is other tools to obfuscate js but I have not tried them.

Edit: For completeness it is a bit better explained here at the end ->

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/cocos2d-js/2-working-environment-and-workflow/2-2-cross-native-browser-game-with-cocos-console/en

Comment: There is a --advanced switch, don't forget to use that! Build process just generates xml build file for closure compiler and runs it, you can play with that xml and try different compiler options